# In Ruby, how do sub, gsub (and other text methods) in shell one-liners work without referring to an object?

Tags: ruby

I saw this piece of code somewhere on the web:

```
ruby -pe 'gsub /^\s*|\s*$/, ""'
```

Evidently this piece of code removes leading and trailing whitespace from each line from STDIN.

I understand the regex and replacement, no problem, but what I don't get is how the method `gsub` is receiving an object to act upon. I understand that the `-p` flag wraps this whole thing in a `while gets; print; ... ; end` block, but **how does `gsub` receive the string to act upon**? At the very least, shouldn't it be a `$_.gsub(..)` instead? How does the current input line get "magically" passed to `gsub`?

Does the code in these Perl-like one-liners get interpreted in a somewhat different manner? I'm looking for a general idea of the differences from traditional, script-based Ruby code. Haven't found a comprehensive set of resources on this, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that this is an instance method defined on Kernel, which magically gets turned on only when you use the -p or -n flag.

```
ruby -pe 'puts method(:gsub);'

#<Method: Object(Kernel)#gsub>
```

See the documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gsub).

Other magical methods I found are `chop`, `print`, and `sub`.

The magical methods are all sent to `$_` implicitly.

Comment: Interesting, so it is more of an interpreter feature then, and not some syntactic magic that I somehow missed.

Comment: Yeah... it's pretty interesting how many Ruby features really are "object-oriented" rather than simply "magical."

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
class Object
  def gsub(*args, &block)
    $_.gsub(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

Since every object is an instance of `Object` (well, almost every object), every object has a `gsub` method now. So, you can call

```
some_object.gsub('foo', 'bar')
```

on *any* object, and it will just work. And since it doesn't matter *what* object you call it on, because it doesn't actually do anything with that object, you might just as well call it on `self`:

```
self.gsub('foo', 'bar')
```

Of course, since `self` is the implicit receiver, this is the same as

```
gsub('foo', 'bar')
```

For methods such as this, which don't actually depend on the receiver, and are only added to  the `Object` class for convenience reasons, it is a common convention to make them `private` so that you cannot accidentally call them with an explicit receiver and then somehow get confused into thinking that this method does something to the receiver.

Also, it is common to put such methods (which are actually intended to be used more like *procedures* than *methods*, i.e. completely independent of their receiver) into the `Kernel` mixin, which is mixed into `Object` instead of directly into the `Object` class to distinguish them from methods that are available to every object but actually *do* depend on its internal state, such as `Object#class`, `Object#to_s` etc.

```
module Kernel
  private

  def gsub(*args, &block)
    $_.gsub(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

Other methods that are defined in this way, which you may have come across already are `require`, `load`, `puts`, `print`, `p`, `gets`, `loop`, `raise`, `rand`, `throw`, `catch`, `lambda`, `proc`, `eval`, `Array`, `Integer`, `Float` etc.

Comment: This is a good explanation of the underlying principles. But it is not quite correct, because Kernel#gsub only gets enabled when the -n or -p flag is specified (as explained in the Ruby docs). You can't call `gsub` within irb, for example.